# Implementing Undo/Redo within a TextArea

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

Im wondering how to implement undo redo functionality with a TextArea. I already have an undoredo framework functionality working, now I have two questions.

1. When do I start/stop a new undo/redo command, eg when a user hits undo, how far back do I go.
2. How do I implement this(1.) in a normal TextArea

My thinking:
I thinking that I should create a new undo command, when anything but a alphanumber+space is hit. To do this I would use the keyDown event and test if the key is alpha num if it is not I will reset the command.

Sound good?

Answer (score 2):

Listening for keydown events would miss any text editing that user does with the mouse (cut/copy/paste).

I think a better approach would be to listen for 'change' event on the control (which fires whenever the content changes through user input), and just push the full content of the control (its 'text' or 'htmlText' attribute) with every change event into a undo-buffer (an Array of Strings). I assume that the memory usage is not an issue (it probably isn't, depending on the expected size of the controls content and number of undo levels).

This way, you implement undo/redo just by copying the corresponding control state (moving up and down through array, basically) in the undo buffer back into the control.

The 'proper' approach would be to track the actual edits, and would be condsiderably more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.When do I start/stop a new undo/redo command, eg when a user hits undo, how far back do I go.

Do you think your users will need to undo multiple steps? If so, then you may want to have a history (e.g. Paint .NET) and allow infinite undo-s. Otherwise, just remember the most recently performed action.

Answer (score 1):

1.) You should listen for the Event.CHANGE event on the TextField and create a history step each time the event is fired. A history step consists in your case of two values: old and new.
Old is the value of the TextField before change, new is its value after the change.

2.) Your history is a sequence of actions or you can use the [Memento Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern). I think actions are much easier to use. A history action has two methods, undo() and redo(). So in undo() you have to say `textField.text = oldContent` and in the redo() method you say `textField.text = newContent`. Your history will also need a pointer to the current action.

3.) To make it a little bit better. You should not listen only for Event.CHANGE but instead listen for the first CHANGE and then the next FOCUS_OUT for that TextField. In that case, a history step is only created once I stop editing the TextField. But it depends on your TextField and how you want to distribute history steps. A multiline TextField should not create a history step only on FOCUS_OUT :)